# Mbed TLS: in-place en-/decryption for OAEP doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, cryptography, embedded, rsa, mbedtls

RSA encryption/decryption works in Mbed TLS when using separate buffers where `plainText`, `cipherText`, and `decryptedText` (i.e. the content of `plainText` and `decryptedText`) are the same.

However, it does not when using just one buffer to perform in-place encryption/decryption. In that case I get gibberish/not correctly encrypted data. Is that just a general limitation or is my code wrong?

[It says here](https://forums.mbed.com/t/in-place-encryption-decryption-with-aes/4531) that "In place cipher is allowed in Mbed TLS, unless specified otherwise." I'm not sure if they are talking about AES or RSA though. I didn't see any remark indicating "otherwise" for OAEP encryption/decryption so I presumed it should work.

Code:

```
size_t sizeDecrypted;
unsigned char plainText[15000] = "yxcvbnm";
unsigned char cipherText[15000];
unsigned char decryptedText[15000];

rtn = mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_encrypt(&rsa, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg, NULL, 0, sizeof("yxcvbnm"), &plainText,  &cipherText);
rtn = mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_decrypt(&rsa, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg, NULL, 0, &sizeDecrypted, &cipherText,  &decryptedText, 15000);
//decryptedText afterwards contains the correctly decrypted text just like plainText
//sizeDecrypted is 8 (because of the binary zero at the end of the string)

unsigned char text[15000] = "yxcvbnm";
rtn = mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_encrypt(&rsa, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg, NULL, 0, sizeof("yxcvbnm"), &text,  &text);
rtn = mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_decrypt(&rsa, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg, NULL, 0, &sizeDecrypted, &text,  &text, 15000);
//someText afterwards doesn't contain the correctly decrypted text/has a different content than plainText
//rtn is always 0, i.e. no error is returned
//sizeDecrypted is 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this will *not* work.

From the repo https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls we look at `library/rsa.c` to get the body of `mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_encrypt`:

```
int mbedtls_rsa_rsaes_oaep_encrypt(mbedtls_rsa_context *ctx,
                                   int (*f_rng)(void *, unsigned char *, size_t),
                                   void *p_rng,
                                   const unsigned char *label, size_t label_len,
                                   size_t ilen,
                                   const unsigned char *input,
                                   unsigned char *output)
{
    size_t olen;
    int ret = MBEDTLS_ERR_ERROR_CORRUPTION_DETECTED;
    unsigned char *p = output;
    unsigned int hlen;

    if (f_rng == NULL) {
        return MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_BAD_INPUT_DATA;
    }

    hlen = mbedtls_md_get_size_from_type((mbedtls_md_type_t) ctx->hash_id);
    if (hlen == 0) {
        return MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_BAD_INPUT_DATA;
    }

    olen = ctx->len;

    /* first comparison checks for overflow */
    if (ilen + 2 * hlen + 2 < ilen || olen < ilen + 2 * hlen + 2) {
        return MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_BAD_INPUT_DATA;
    }

    memset(output, 0, olen);

    *p++ = 0;

    /* Generate a random octet string seed */
    if ((ret = f_rng(p_rng, p, hlen)) != 0) {
        return MBEDTLS_ERROR_ADD(MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_RNG_FAILED, ret);
    }

    p += hlen;

    /* Construct DB */
    ret = compute_hash((mbedtls_md_type_t) ctx->hash_id, label, label_len, p);
    if (ret != 0) {
        return ret;
    }
    p += hlen;
    p += olen - 2 * hlen - 2 - ilen;
    *p++ = 1;
    if (ilen != 0) {
        memcpy(p, input, ilen);
    }

    /* maskedDB: Apply dbMask to DB */
    if ((ret = mgf_mask(output + hlen + 1, olen - hlen - 1, output + 1, hlen,
                        (mbedtls_md_type_t) ctx->hash_id)) != 0) {
        return ret;
    }

    /* maskedSeed: Apply seedMask to seed */
    if ((ret = mgf_mask(output + 1, hlen, output + hlen + 1, olen - hlen - 1,
                        (mbedtls_md_type_t) ctx->hash_id)) != 0) {
        return ret;
    }

    return mbedtls_rsa_public(ctx, output, output);
}
```

Note the following:

After some initial integrity checks, we have:

```
memset(output, 0, olen);
```

If `output == input`, this *trashes* the input buffer (or portion thereof) *before* the input buffer is examined.

So, the buffers *must* be distinct and non-overlapping.

Comment: Bad documentation for cryptography libs, who'd thunk ;)